# Unable to import ApacheHttpClient despite it being present as part of a java library

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I am using the java SDK for s3 version 2.

I want to import `import software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient` but intellij idea says that class does not exist. But when i search for the class i can see that it is present.

[image]

Here's the pom definition.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/s3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.56</version>
    </dependency>
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. If the issue persists, please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency that you are using, adds a transitive runtime dependency of `software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client` (which has the `ApacheHttpClient` class in it) to the project. That's why you can see the `ApacheHttpClient` class in the search results. However, since this is only a runtime dependency, you can't use the `ApacheHttpClient` class in the code. To use `ApacheHttpClient` in the code, you need the compile time dependency of `software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client`. For that, you can add the below dependency with the version of your desire.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>apache-client</artifactId>
   <version>2.20.56</version>
</dependency>
```

You can refer this for more details -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/http-configuration-apache.html